# Python printing more than I want

Tags: python

I am new to programming. In the code below, when I am entering any string as an answer to 'what is your score?', it is printing both 'Bad Score, Try Again' and 'F'.

Why? Please help. Thanks!

```
score = raw_input('what is your score?')
try:
    score = float(score)
except:
    score = -1
    print 'Bad Score, Try Again'
if score >= 0.9:
    print "A"
elif score >= 0.8:
    print "B"
elif score >= 0.7:
    print "C"
elif score >= 0.6:
    print "D"
if score < 0.6:
    print "F"
```

Comment: I'm not sure how to answer this. You seem to be aware that the statements in a program are executed from top to bottom. So my counterquestion to you would be: why would the program NOT print "F" after you set `score` to -1?

Comment: Your final `if` should be an `elif`.

Comment: it because of your last if statement. It should be `elif` not `if` i m going to guess. because `-1`

Comment: The last if doesn't belong to the rest of the cases. Please use `elif` or `else` for the `F` block

Comment: Making the if an elif won't solve the problem, guys.

Comment: `if score< 0.6 and score >= 0`

Comment: Runs the same with elif too.

Comment: @timgeb It's a massive part of the problem/logic tho :P

Comment: @Torxed no, the < 0.6 case is already mutually exclusive to the previous cases.

Comment: Yea i retract my statement, shouldn't be on the loo with a phone trying to answer programming logic. My bad!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put all of your code into the try statement it will work properly.

```
score = raw_input('what is your score?')
try:
    score = float(score)
    if score >= 0.9:
        print "A"
    elif score >= 0.8:
        print "B"
    elif score >= 0.7:
        print "C"
    elif score >= 0.6:
        print "D"
    elif score < 0.6:
        print "F"
except:
    score = -1
    print 'Bad Score, Try Again'
```

Comment: If it works I would appreciate if you accept my answer.

Answer (score 2):

When string you write can't be converted to a float value, an exception is raised and catched by except, so 'Bad score' message is displayed and score is assigned a value of -1.

Since exception was catched, execution continues. Since current score value, -1, is less than 0.6, 'F' is printed as well.

Try moving exception catching to the end of your code:

```
score = raw_input('what is your score?')
try:
    score = float(score)
    if score >= 0.9:
        print "A"
    elif score >= 0.8:
        print "B"
    elif score >= 0.7:
        print "C"
    elif score >= 0.6:
        print "D"
    elif score < 0.6:
        print "F"
except:
    score = -1
    print 'Bad Score, Try Again'
```

Answer (score 1):

When you input a string the following code is printing 'Bad Score, Try Again' and setting score to -1

```
score = raw_input('what is your score?')
try:
    score = float(score)
except:
    score = -1
    print 'Bad Score, Try Again'
```

Then this code executes, score(-1) is less than 0.6 do 'F' is printed

```
if score >= 0.9:
    print "A"
elif score >= 0.8:
    print "B"
elif score >= 0.7:
    print "C"
elif score >= 0.6:
    print "D"
if score < 0.6:
    print "F"
```

Perhaps what you want is:

```
score = raw_input('what is your score?')
try:
    score = float(score)
except:
    score = -1

if score >= 0.9:
    print "A"
elif score >= 0.8:
    print "B"
elif score >= 0.7:
    print "C"
elif score >= 0.6:
    print "D"
elif score >= 0:
    print "F"
else:
    print 'Bad Score, Try Again'
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because your `if` statements are outside the `except` clause and are executed when control leaves it.

You're setting `score` to `-1`, which is less than `0.6`, so `F` is printed.

You'll have to move the entire `if`s to the `except` clause to make it work. Or you can change the last `if` to `elif` or `else`.

Comment: ok! What should I input for except for this to work properly?

Comment: @user5974272, I don't quite understand your question... You'r got two ways to solve this: either move the `if`s to the `except` clause either change the last `if` to `elif` pr even `else` (in that case you don't need `score<0.6`)